# What does it mean for long time waiting for a Application?

Tags: time-stamp, waiting

You can find the following patent is filed on 2007, however, till now, it has not been approved. Does it means this application will not be granted? or what does it mean?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Applications which begin with a "WO" are never meant to become real patents. They will always remain applications, filed under the World Intellectual Property Organization (WIPO). This is an easy way of filling many documents once and then choose countries and regions in which you'd like your application to become a patent.

So after a predetermined time period, which depends on the country, you are requested to indicate at which countries you want to proceed.1-1 1/2 year after publication, this should be available either through google, or through other databases (WIPO, EPO).

In the above case, the application entered national phases of EP, US and CA (EP is a regional treaty and today contains almost all European countries). You can see the relevant numbers in the "also published as" section of the google page. However, none of those had any lack, all of them have been abandoned.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much @chempatent1981

Comment: Then another question: Which database could search all the latest patents within 1-1.5 year? You have said all the patent can be searched in google patent 1-1.5 year after the publication, right? I want to know what can we do before this time. Thanks.

Comment: I am afraid you cannot search earlier than that. The time span between filling and publishing is usually 18 months, unless the applicant requests explicitly for an early publication. I don't see that so often. There are many reasons why this time span exists and a major one is that you might want to file your application elsewhere (and you need some time to evaluate your strategy, your invention and your budjet, I guess!).